# How many ways are there to color vertexes of a $12-gon$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to color vertexes of a $12-gon$?

In my opinion we have $2^{12}$ cases If they were on a line but then we calculated every case except full red and full blue case twice so I got the answer $\frac{2^{12}-2}{12}+2$ but the problem is $12$ doesn't divide $2^{12}-2$.

Comment: Consider Polya theory. You need to take reflections and rotations (Dihedral group) into account.

Comment: The number of overcounting for each coloring is quite different.